# How can I let elements inside a xul tab element receive mouse events?

Tags: tabs, firefox-addon, mouseevent, xul, xbl

Considering this xul markup:

```
<tabbox>
  <tabs>
    <tab>
      <textbox width="50">
    </tab>
  </tabs>
  <!-- ... -->
</tabbox>
```

... I am unable to select the `<textbox>` with my mouse. The `<tab>` shields off any mouse event to child nodes, it seems. How can I let the `<textbox>` receive mouse events?

I've tried attributes like `mousethrough="always"` and `mousethrough="never"` on both the `<tab>` and `<textbox>` element, but to be honest, I'm not entirely sure what that attribute is supposed to do. Furthermore I believe it's only applicable to elements in a `<stack>`.

I've also tried `allowevents="true"` on the `<tab>`, but that doesn't do anything either, unfortunately.

What *does* work, to some extent, is passing the focus through JavaScript, with something like:

```js
theTab.addEventListener( 'focus', function( event ) {
  theTextbox.focus();
} );
```

... but that is too clunky, and still doesn't make the `<textbox>` behave properly (unable to select the text, etc.). I'd probably need to implement this for a whole slew of events, then.

So, what, if any, simple steps can I take to have child nodes of a `<tab>` element behave as expected?

Or do I perhaps need to completely extend the tab XBL, because a tab generally is not meant to behave the way I intend here?

**edit:**

It just occurred to me that I *can* probably visually fake it a little by omitting the tab altogether and just have a `<textbox>`, that appears like a tab, with:

```
<textbox id="someId"/>

#someId {
  -moz-appearance: tab
}
```

... and try to incorporate that somehow in the `<tabs>` element.

Still, I'd rather have a solution with an actual `<tab>`, such that I can let the `<tab>` behave as an actual `<tab>`, to some extent, as well (popping up a bit, when selected, etc.).

Comment: Just to be clear: Based on your XUL, you want the `label` of the `<tab>` to be a `<textbox>`, correct?  It is not that you want the `<tab>` contents to be/include a `<textbox>`? Either way, please expand your code just a bit to include some `<tabpanels><tabpanel>` content to show that this unusual usage is intentional, not a misunderstanding of how to use [`<tabbox>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Tutorial/Tabboxes).

Comment: When using [XUL Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL_Explorer) to test this, and having added an additional tab for testing, I found that it worked more, or less, as expected (`<textbox>` content received focus and could be edited) under some conditions (that appeared to involve switching focus to another window.  I have not yet determined the exact conditions for it to work (not that this intermittent functionality is sufficient, just interesting).

Comment: @Makyen No, you understood correct. The `<tabpanel>`s content are irrelevant — I want the label of a `<tab>` to be editable. For an extension I'm developing I want my users to be able to rename `<tab>`s inline. When a `<tab>` is selected, and they click some edit button (which will be next to the tabs), the `<tab>`'s label should become an editable `<textbox>`.

Comment: How about having the edit button open a pop-up where the user can edit the text and then have your JavaScript apply the edited text to the `<tab>`'s `label` attribute? This might make more sense from a UI point of view, if you are going to have a button to initiate the edit instead of having it editable 100% of the time. This way there is a clear end to the user editing the label with an already understood OK/Cancel dialog.

Comment: @Makyen I see. That's kind of what is happening in Firefox as well, now that you mentioned it. I guess I'm kind of abusing a `<tab>` element here, in a way that they were not intended to be used. After inspecting the XBL bindings of `<tab>`, and related elements, I have this faint suspicion that I will have to build the element from scratch myself, with XBL. :-( For instance, when I look at the implementation of the close button on a browser tab, they seem to jump through loops as well to register the mouse click on the close button (which is actually handled by tabbrowser-tab**s**)

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I like the pop-up idea if using a `<button`> to initiate editing of the `<tab>`'s label. If you were using a `<checkbox>` to indicate all `<tab>` labels were editable (or a context menu to "rename"), I would expect the label to be directly editable, but the `<button>` implies a pop-up to me. It would be easy to have edits in the pop-up dynamically change the label so the user can see what it would look like while editing. This would be easier to code, and require less testing than modifying the XBL for potentially all of `<tabbox>`, `<tabs>` and `<tab>`.

Comment: @Makyen That would have to be a last resort. I really want the user experience to be as smooth and inline, with as little dialog windows, as possible. Before using any pop-ups I'd probably just resort to a `<textbox>` without a `<tab>` wrapper then.

Comment: @Makyen Sorry about the constant delay, I keep getting interrupted here, and by chance constantly answer an earlier comment of yours, when you just submitted a new comment. ;-) Anyway, I see what you are getting at, but some type of inline editing capability appeals more to me than pop-ups/dialog windows.

Comment: @Makyen PS.: The `<tab>`s will actually have context menus, with the option to rename, as well. And the actual position of the edit button is not entirely determined yet, I may actually end up placing an edit icon inside the `<tab>`, in stead of next to the `<tab>`s. I haven't fully decided yet. It's just tentative design for now.

Comment: No problem...Then I would suggest something other than a `<button>` to initiate the edit.  A `<button>` implies flow of UI (e.g. things like bringing up a pop-up, or initiating an action).  A `<checkbox>` or `<toolbarbutton type="checkbox"/>` implies change of state (like making the label editable). On the other hand, a edit icon `<button>` inside the `<tab>` might be reasonable, although that will need mouse events also.